# SSIS script task - Having issue while parsing xml

Tags: xml, ssis, script-task

Here is the sample xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ServerInfoArrayResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Result xmlns="http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/ServerAdmin.asmx">true</Result>
  <ResultCode xmlns="http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/ServerAdmin.asmx">1</ResultCode>
  <Message xmlns="http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/ServerAdmin.asmx" />
  <Servers xmlns="http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/ServerAdmin.asmx">
    <ServerInfo>
      <ServerID>1234</ServerID>      
      <Name>server1234</Name>
    </ServerInfo>
</Servers>
</ServerInfoArrayResult>
```

I am trying to get ServerID and Name. here is the code i have. But it's not returning anything.

```html
ar nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    

    foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("/Servers/ServerInfo"))
    {
        //Add new row to the output buffer for each employee node in the XML file
        this.ServerInfoBuffer.AddRow();

        //Assign values to the columns.

        //Read the 1st attribute of the node Employee
        this.ServerInfoBuffer.ServerID = xNode.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
        
        this.ServerInfoBuffer.ServerName = xNode.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Down vote without comment? Explain yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```html
 XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/ServerAdmin.asmx");

        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("//ServerInfoArrayResult/a:Servers/a:ServerInfo", nsmgr))
```